# SQL UPDATE question for large fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a table with a field that I wish to work with in a mySQL database.  It's function is a long list of keywords used for fulltext search so the field is rather long.

For example:

```
Table
'data_index'
shirt t-shirt list item red black brown green purple sleeveless...etc for about 20 lines
```

I would like to match a separate string, lets define as:

```
$string  = "teeshirt shert shertt shirtt";
```

I would like to ADD these items in $string to the list without having to grab the entire value in each data_index field.  Essentially I don't want to have to use the UPDATE sql command and use the entire data_index value in this query.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename SET data_index = CONCAT(data_index, 'your new keywords') WHERE ...
```

Comment: I am so unfamiliar with SQL, didn't know this existed.  No brainer! Thanks!